# Map is not showing up in in simple sidebar bootstrap

Tags: dictionary, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I'm using simple sidebar bootstrap but some reason the map is not showing up. I thought just putting `<div id="map"></div>` inside the page content is enough but the map is not showing up. Did I miss something? Thanks! Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/william251082/pen/rGNPqr

Comment: Thanks I dumped my code here: https://codepen.io/william251082/pen/rGNPqr

Answer (score 0):

```
Check your api key <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
  key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
----------------------
    window.initMap = function() {
      var location = {lat: 51.47672559, lng: -3.17107379};
      var markerloc = {lat: 51.476852, lng: -3.167869};
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: location,
         scrollwheel: false,
         zoom: 17
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: markerloc,
         map: map,
         title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    };
```